# Python module: main.py can't find modules.py although it's in the same folder

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to import functions from tc_modules.py into tc_main.py but it returns the error:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tc_modules'" ... although both files are in the same folder!

I've made a simple test in the same folder:

#modul_test.py

```
def probe():
    print ("Good")
```

and
#importer.py

```
   import tc_modules
   import modul_test
   modul_test.probe()
```

it works perfectly for modul_test but I receive the same error with tc_modules. I figured out that something is wrong with the tc_modules file, but I don't know what.
Can someone help me with this?

One more question regarding modules.
Where are modules executed... in the main.py "environment" or what?
I'm asking that because I have some variables in tc_main.py that have to be used by functions from tc_modules. Do main and modules files have to be cross-referenced?

Comment: Namespace can be an issue. Have you tried to call the modules before the function is created?

Comment: You were right! I copied the content from tc_modules to modul_test and it works!